# Is there a way to tell all methods inside a class to do function call without writing those function calls to every method

Tags: scala

I'm coding request calls to tens of services which should be authorized.

I noticed I have written a lot of copy&paste code to the beginning of all methods inside service classes because they all must be authorized before using any services.

Little example...

```
class AuthorizationService {
  val authorized = List("James", "007")

  def authorize(user: String) = {
    if (!authorized.contains(user)) throw new RuntimeException(s"User '$user' not authorized")
  }
}

class Service1 {

  val authorizationService = new AuthorizationService

  def doThis(user: String) = {
    authorizationService.authorize(user)
    println(s"User '$user' did this")
  }

  def doThat(user: String) = {
    authorizationService.authorize(user)
    println(s"User '$user' did that")
  }
}
```

Now imagine there are 30 service classes with three methods each and I continue to do authorization like the way I have I end up writing 90 functions calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe ... It still requires your service to change, but not as much:

```
 object AuthToken {
    implicit def auth(s: String)(implicit service: AuthService) = { 
      service.authorize(s)
      AuthToken(s)
    }
 }
 case class AuthToken private[AuthToken] (s: String) {
    override def toString = s;
 }

 class Service1 {
   implicit val authorizationService = new AuthorizationService
   def doThis(user: AuthToken) = {
     println(s"User '$user' did this")
   }
 }
```

Now, if you do `new Service1().doThis("James")`, it will implicitly call your auth service first to convert the name into token.

Answer (score 1):

You could use it like this:

```
object Tester {

  class AuthorizationService {
    val authorized = List("James", "007")

    def authorize(user: String) = {
      if (!authorized.contains(user)) throw new RuntimeException(s"User '$user' not authorized")
    }
  }


  def authorize(businessLogic: => Unit)(implicit
                                        authorizationService: AuthorizationService,
                                        user: String): Unit = {
    // authorization logic
    authorizationService.authorize(user)
    println(s"User '$user' did this")

    // actual code that needs to be executed
    businessLogic
  }

  class Service1(implicit val authorizationService: AuthorizationService) {
    def doThis(implicit user: String) = authorize {
      println("doThis()")
    }

    def doThat(implicit user: String) = authorize {
      println("doThat()")
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    implicit val authorizationService = new AuthorizationService
    val s = new Service1()
    s.doThat("James")
    s.doThat("007")
    s.doThat("Neo")
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked also but I do not have enough reputation points to upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use a crude composition pattern:

```
class ServiceAuthorizationExecutor {
   def call(user: String, delegate: DELGATE_TYPE) = {
      authorizationService.authorize(user)
      delegate()
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a classic AOP problem. The last time I looked at AOP was 12 years ago though, so I'm not sure what the state of it all is.

Comment: This should be a comment, it doesn't answer the question.